# Is there a an equivalent doCallRealMethod for spies (aka doCallMockMethod)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to mock out a class due to one third party required dependency, so I can unit test it (I cannot remove this dependency).

So what I've done is `mocked` out the class and then utilized `Mockito.doRealMethod()` for all the function calls, but I feel this sort of abstracts what is being really done.

When in reality I want the real class and just want to mock out that one call.

Comment: Could you provide code that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Partial mocking of a class is supported via spy in Mockito. See the [Mockito documentation on partial mocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html) for more information.

Another possibility may be to use `org.mockito.Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS`, such as:

```
YourClass YOUR_MOCK = Mockito.mock( YourClass.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS );
```

Comment: This would work, only thing is the call I am using requires RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS aka Mockito.mock( YourClass.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS );

So when mock that one out, can I still use RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS?

Comment: No, but you only have to mock one method. Just return a mock created with RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS should solve your issue, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the real method on a [spy](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) like

```
Mockito.doReturn("foobar").when(mySpy).myMethod();
```

Comment: This does seem what I need, but I can't figure out how to get it to work on a nested method. So `Mockito.doReturn("foobar").when(mySpy).myMethod1().myMethod2().myMethod()3;` Ultimately I don't even need the result for myMethod1 and myMethod2 to work.But when I do the above it is trying to get the return type of myMethod1 and not myMethod3 but `Mockito.doReturn("foobar").when(mySpy.myMethod1().myMethod2()).myMethod()3;`  returns 
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here